# ClickOnce and .NET 7: User settings not being updated

Tags: clickonce, visual-studio-2022, strongname, .net-7.0, user.config

I've updated my vb Windows Forms Application from .net 4.7.2 to .net 7
So every time I Use ClickOnce now to Publish, when the new version is Loaded the User Settings are set back to default.
When a user then updates a User Setting it now creates a new folder inside the Appdata/Local/Application Folder, and adds a new user.config file.
Doing research on this Subject its seems I would need to Use a Strong Name to Sign the Assembly in .net5 and .net6, but this tab seems to be missing from the project properties, in Visual Studio 2022 with .net7

ScreenShot of New Folder Creation

[image: 1]

ScreenShot of Missing Tab

[image: 2]

So what used to Happen is every time I published using ClickOnce, the User settings would stay in the same folder, and now its not recognising that folder and creates a new folder when the user saves a new setting.

Any help here would be appreciated...

Comment: Ended up rolling the project back, and now everything works again.
Hope this may be fixed in the Future.